# Weird SQL behavior with INSERT and WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, insert

I have this query, which should insert an amount if an amount equals or higher for the same ID doesn't already exists in the table.

I tried this under MySQL 5.1 and MSSQL 2k5 :

**MySQL**

INSERT IGNORE INTO test (id, amount) 
SELECT 6, 50 FROM test
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE amount >= 50 AND id = 6) LIMIT 1

**MSSQL**

INSERT INTO test (id, amount) 
SELECT 6, 50 FROM test 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM test WHERE amount >= 50 AND id = 6)

This query works fine IF there is already at least one entry in the table. If the table is empty, it will never work. It's the same behavior under MySQL (5.1) and MSSQL (2005).
I don't understand why. Anybody has an explanation and a way to fix this query to work even if the table is completely empty?

**EDIT : I need this for MySQL mostly...**

**UPDATE :** I started a new question specifically for MySQL :
[MySQL Problem with inserting a row with certain conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309889/mysql-insert-with-conditions-problem)

Comment: is SELECT TOP 1 1  = SELECT TOP 1 * ?

Comment: @Chris i think so and in an "exists(select..." i think there is no top needed and the 1 is not needed too.

Comment: I still wasn't able to make it work under MySQL... if you have another way of doing this it would be fine too.. Maybe a left join would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because the select statement selects values of 6 and 50 based on the number of rows returned. Since your table is empty - no rows are returned to have these values.

Modify it to

```
 INSERT INTO test (id, amount) SELECT 6, 50 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM test WHERE amount >= 50 AND id = 6)
```

Comment: It doesn't work in MySQL... It doesn't like that there is no FROM clause before the WHERE :(

Comment: It doesn't work under MySQL. You can't have a missing FROM clause and if you add it, it's still the same problem when there are no rows...

Comment: I accepted it because it works under MSSQL and I wasn't precise enough for MySQL. I started a new question for MySQL, check update in my post for the link. Thanks :)

Comment: Seems backwards given "EDIT : I need this for MySQL mostly..."

Comment: If you add "FROM DUAL" it works on MySQL - DUAL is apparently like a dummy table that always acts as if it has one row.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO test (id, amount) 
SELECT 6, 50 FROM test 
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM test WHERE amount >= 50 AND id = 6) = 0
```

Comment: 0 rows affected when the table is empty :|  Works when there is at least one row in the table... Weird hu :P

Comment: this don't work like expected, i'v tested and got annother solution

Answer (score 0):

I tried this step by step:

```
    -- create a test-table with one entry
SELECT id = 1, amount = 50 
into #TEST

-- see if statement works when table is not empty
INSERT INTO #test (id, amount)  
SELECT id = 6, amount = 50 
FROM #test  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #test WHERE amount >= 50 AND id = 6) 

-- show content of test-table
select * from #test

-- empty the test table
truncate table #test

-- try to insert a first dataentry
INSERT INTO #test (id, amount)  
SELECT id = 6, amount = 50 
FROM #test  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #test WHERE amount >= 50 AND id = 6) 
union
SELECT id = 6, amount = 50 
where (SELECT C = COUNT(*)  FROM #test WHERE amount >= 50 AND id = 6) = 0

-- show content of test-table
select * from #test

-- remove Test-table
drop table #test
```

First i tried to reproduce the behaviour and yes it's weird. The union - think manages the empty-table case and voilà this works fine.

Comment: Again, it doesn't seems to work with MySQL.  SELECT id = 6, amount = 50 doesn't work and MySQL seems to need a "FROM" clause. :(

Answer (score 0):

ok, thats the real question. Try this, using a second table (#test2):

```
    -- create a test-table with one entry
SELECT id = 1, amount = 50 
into #TEST

-- create a second test-table with one entry
SELECT id = 1, amount = 50 
into #TEST2

-- see if statement works when table is not empty
INSERT INTO #test (id, amount)  
SELECT id = 6, amount = 50 
FROM #test  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #test WHERE amount >= 50 AND id = 6) 

-- show content of test-table
select * from #test

-- empty the test table
truncate table #test

INSERT INTO #test (id, amount) SELECT 6, 50 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #test WHERE amount >= 50 AND id = 6)  

-- try to insert a first dataentry
INSERT INTO #test (id, amount)  
SELECT id = 6, amount = 50 
FROM #test  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #test WHERE amount >= 50 AND id = 6) 
union
SELECT id = 6, amount = 50 
from #test2
where (SELECT C = COUNT(*)  FROM #test) = 0


-- show content of test-table
select * from #test

-- remove Test-table
drop table #test
```

(Assuming you know the tables with a preceeding #, this are temporary tables in MS-SQL).

BonyT has explained the reason already.

Comment: Tried this under MYSQL :
INSERT INTO test (id, amount)  
SELECT id = 6, amount = 50 
FROM test  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test WHERE amount >= 50 AND id = 6) 
UNION
SELECT id = 6, amount = 50 
FROM test2
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C  FROM test) = 0

Still the same problem ?