# MySQL Problem with inserting a row with certain conditions 

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a problem inserting a row in a MySQL table when the table is completely empty.
I use this query :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO test (id, amount) 
SELECT 6, 50 FROM test WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE amount >= 50 AND id = 6) LIMIT 1
```

It works fine when there is at least one entry in the table, whatever the data in the columns are. It doesn't work if the table is completely empty.

Basically, I want to insert a row if a row with the same ID and an amount equals or higher doesn't exists.

I tried with a COUNT also, still the same problem. Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only thing wrong with this is on line two, remove `FROM test`.. You can't `select 6, 50 from test`..  6 and 50 are not columns in test, and test has no records.  Try it like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO test (id, amount) 
SELECT * from (select 6, 50) as a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test 
                  WHERE amount >= 50 AND id = 6)
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test 
                  WHERE amount >= 50 AND i' at line 3
My query does work, only when there is at least one row in the table. That's the problem :(

Comment: @tink01 ok, try the update I just posted... I've never quite done it this way before.  Usually I am inserting data from other tables conditionally.

Comment: If you use this, it's safer to add a "AS" for the columns like : (select 6 as col1, 50 as col2) or you'll get a "column already exists" if there are similar values.